# Javascript: Array isn't changing, it's bug?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array not changing with both `[...].splice(index, 1, change)` and `[...][index] = change` methods. See example for more information.

Note: I am know about js, it changes anywhere except `t === 1`.
Can anyone explain this behavior, is this a known bug, or is there a solution?

I want to find solution for it because i want create 'Interpolator for Tweening library' with support relative string (object, array, number are supports in later, i will add).

```js
// RegExp variables
var numRegExp =
  /\s+|([A-Za-z?().,{}:""[\]#]+)|([-+/*%]+=)?([-+*/%]+)?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.?\d+)(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?/g;

// Helpers
function s2f(val) {
  var floatedVal = parseFloat(val);
  return typeof floatedVal === "number" && !isNaN(floatedVal) ? floatedVal : val;
}
var relativeModes = {
  '+=': 1,
  '-=': 1,
  '*=': 2,
  '/=': 3,
  '%=': 4
};

function r2n(s, e) {
  if (typeof e === 'number') {
    return e - s;
  } else {
    var rv = relativeModes[e.substr(0, 2)],
      v = e.substr(2);
    if (rv === 1) {
      var e2 = e[0] + v;
      return (s + parseFloat(e2)) - s;
    } else if (rv === 2) {
      return (s * +v) - s;
    } else if (rv === 3) {
      return (s / +v) - s;
    } else if (rv === 4) {
      return (s * (+v / 100)) - s;
    }
  }
  return e;
}

function s2n(str) {
  return str.match(numRegExp).map(s2f);
}

// Splitted functions
var stringTween = function(s, e, d) {
  d = d !== undefined ? d : 10000;
  var sv = s2n(s);
  var ev = s2n(e);
  var rv = ev.map(function(e, i) {
    return typeof e === 'string' && e.indexOf('=') === 1 ? e : null;
  });
  ev = ev.map(function(e, i) {
    return rv[i] !== null ? r2n(sv[i], e) : typeof e === 'number' ? e - sv[i] : e;
  });
  return function(t) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = ev.length; i < len; i++) {
      var a = sv[i],
        b = ev[i],
        r = rv[i];
      str += typeof b === 'number' ? a + b * t : a;
      if (t === 1 && r !== null) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'This script executes <code>t === 1</code>, relative value isn\'t null, but <code>sv</code> or <code>ev</code> not changes, this is BUG?' + '<br/>';
        sv[i] += b;
        ev[i] = r2n(sv[i], r);
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
}

// Test case
var st = performance.now(),
  rep = 1;
requestAnimationFrame(function anim(time) {
  var t = (time - st) / 2000;
  t = t > 1 ? 1 : t;
  document.body.innerHTML += stringTween('translate3d(10px, 20px, 30px)', 'translate3d(+=20px, 30px, 35px)')(t) + '<br/>';
  if (t === 1) {
    if (rep > 0) {
      rep--;
      st = time
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
});
```

```css
#note {
  color: red;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tested mode</h1>
<h2>
  - Chrome<br/> - NodeJS 6.x<br/> - IE Edge <br/>
</h2>
<p id="note">Please not teach me by not related answer like use selector outside frame-loop, optimize it, reduce relayout, cache node</p>

<body>

</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: It is really a lot of code. Try to reduce it please.

Comment: btw, `| 0` looks clever, but it reduces the range of the number to 32 bit.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? You can't expect people to decrypt whatever you want to achieve here.

Comment: I reduced code and removed unnecessary code, i hope now someone can help to fix this, as i am need relative tweening support, when i done i wil publish it to npm for own and others usage. on NPM registry has string tween, but not relative support yet. This would be first interpolator that supports relative (i try to be smartest, lightweight and fast interpolator)

Comment: @cbll I try to get relative string tweening (object, array, number are support in later), this is interpolator function for string only

Comment: Someone here know about JS-bugs?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function variables can't shared across functions